# Is registering beans to the Spring context an anti-paradigm?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, javabeans

Suppose that we have a configuration file as a resource of our application. 
This resource file contains a key that includes an array of objects, each declaring a configuration to instantiate `Foo` objects.

Normally, we could annotate our types with `@Component|Service|Configuration|...`, hence it will be available in Spring's application context, or we could simply declare bean factories to show how the object should be instantiated in the application container.

This time, I would like to create a number of objects with the same type, i.e. `Foo`, but with a different configuration. Each of them will have a unique bean name, so I could `@Autowired` all of those beans simply declaring a `Map<String, Foo>` field, where it gets injected by the Spring Framework as a key-value pair list containing beans associated with their names.

The question is more philosophically. Spring Framework utilizes principles of *inversion of control* by using *dependency injection*, so we're offloading the management of the lifecycle of the objects our classes dependent to.

Is it an anti-paradigm to register that beans programmatically, since Spring does not take care of what I did in the configuration file?

Comment: You mean you would like to programatically register spring beans by implementing `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` ? and would like to know if doing such thing will violate the principles of IOC / DI ?

Comment: @KenChan  Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out, IoC/DI is all about delegating the responsibility of object construction and management to the framework.

**Having said that, if you extend the framework — i.e., implement [*BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor*](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/support/BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor.html) — Spring will still manage the beans and the following injections. This won't go against IoC definition.**

Now, going into further detail, if you programmatically access the context at runtime from miscellaneous classes to obtain beans, you'll be breaking the IoC pattern. By doing this, you'll give back to the classes the responsibility of knowing how to construct themselves.

**My thumb rule is, the less my classes know about Spring's implementation details (loose coupling), the better.** Also, if you register the beans following Spring's lifecycle (not creating the beans after *BeanFactoryPostProcessor* runs), you'll just flow with the natural path of the framework.

Answer (score 0):

By using `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor` , you can programmatically define the configuration for a bean. It is just a bean configuration but not a bean instance. Spring will create the bean instance and manage its life cycle based on the bean configuration.

So at the end the bean is still created and managed by the Spring which does not violate IoC philosophy which promote let container to create a bean rather the developer themselves.

Answer (score 0):

Registering the Spring beans and Spring managing the life-cycle of those beans are separate operations.
One needs to make all the beans available to Spring so Spring can manage their life-cycle.

There are several ways of registering the beans (not an exhaustive list).

- XML files
- Java Annotations - `@ComponentScan`/`@Configuration`/`@Component` are some examples of such registration.
- PostProcessors are another way to do the same.
- `spring.factories` - You can even add all your beans under `META-INF/spring.factories` under a special property and make all the beans available to your Spring boot application.
- [Candidate component index](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-scanning-index)
- Functional style of registration with Suppliers which is lazy with no reflection costs. See [1]

You can even mix and match one or more of the above mechanisms and Spring will honor all of them.

To answer your specific question given above:

`> Is it an anti-paradigm to register that beans programmatically, since Spring does not take care of what I did in the configuration file?`

Definitely not. You may register the beans in one or more ways but that doesn't change how Spring will treat them when it comes down to wiring the dependencies.

The reason there are so many registration mechanisms is to give the App developer the choice to pick the most suitable mechanism depending on their use-case hopefully migrating to newer more optimized methods.

When you ask for all the beans of a certain type in a `Map<String, Foo>`, Spring will provide you all the dependencies irrespective of how they got registered.

Stick to a few registration mechanisms (as small as possible) that work for you, so that your fellow team-mates can understand and maintain how the beans are being wired up.

[1] - [Whats' new in Spring 5.x](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/wiki/What%27s-New-in-Spring-Framework-5.x)